# Why can't we access Apple's implementation files?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learning about Objective-C runtime. I can access to NSObject.m root class to see how it works but I can not acces to NSProxy.m or UITableView.m files.

Why does Apple enable access to some implementation files and others not?

I've searched in Google but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't have access to *any* of Apple's Cocoa source code. It's secret.

You may have found online some open source version of NSObject (for the Darwin project or OpenStep / GNUStep or similar), but that is not Apple's Cocoa source code.

Apple may choose to provide an open source version of some of their code, e.g. http://www.opensource.apple.com/. But even then you don't really know what they are using under the hood.

Comment: Thanks matt, that makes sense.